# Unity Desktop: Tray icons of some apps not showing anymore (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: unity, 22.04, unity-dash, system-tray

Like a ghost that you can't get rid of, here is an issue that was actually solved many years ago and has now been appearing again for a couple of months: Some tray icons don't appear anymore, in my case those of **Signal** and **Heroic Games Launcher**. They are still working properly with Gnome Desktop.
Tray icons of other apps still do work with Unity too, e.g. Psensor, Diodon, System Load Indicator, Skype, Steam, Telegram, OBS.

But I had already started a [thread at Signal community](https://community.signalusers.org/t/after-update-to-6-4-0-tray-icon-is-missing-linux-ubuntu-unity/51263), with the result that it is probably not a bug on Signal. It could be due to the "Electron" version but that's unclear to me. Problems with a missing tray icon are not known in the Heroic Forum.

The old solutions from the years up to 2016 no longer work, the systray whitelist as a configuration variable no longer exists. I do not know how to continue.

Using Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS + Unity 7.5.1+22.04.20211026.2-0ubuntu1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it turns out that the problem is related to a certain version of the Electron software framework which those programs are using. So, it will only be fixed with updates, which we have to wait for.

This is a workaround from [here](https://discourse.ruds.io/t/system-tray-icons-some-program-icons-do-not-appear-anymore/408/5) as a temporary solution:

1. Copy the .desktop icon file from the program source to `~/.local/share/applications/`
2. Add `env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity7` to the line starting with "Exec=" as first argument before the actual command.

If it already starts with "Exec=env {something}" then add only `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity7` to that.

Packet installs have their .desktop files in `/usr/share/applications/`. Snap installs have theirs at `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` and Flatpak installs haven them at `/var/lib/flatpak/app/program.name.here/current/active/export/share/applications/`.

Once the Electron versions are aligned (in the future), the new .desktop files can be deleted.